# List of tables having two specific columns

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to get list of tables in oracle database which has two specific columns (together, not either) .

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name in ('CLOUMNNAME1','CLOUMNNAME2');
```

It gives me all the tables which has either one or both. but I need those ones who have both columns.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2144602?tstart=0 gave me the mentioned query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find tables that return 2 rows:

```
SELECT table_owner, TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where column_name in ('CLOUMNNAME1','CLOUMNNAME2') 
GROUP BY table_owner, TABLE_NAME HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

EDIT: added "table_owner" to avoid tables from different schemas that share table_name